# Regular Expression to switch out parts of file names?

Tags: regex, replace, expression, rename

I have hundreds of files with names such as these:

```
foo.13.01.02.place.title.of.take.mp4
foo.13.04.23.office.other.title.altogether.mp4
foo.13.12.30.street.yet.another.title.mp4
```

"foo" would be the production company (always the same), the date follows `(yy/mm/dd)`, then the place of filming and finally the title of the take that was shot.

I now want to rename all those files to be in the form

`place - title (foo - date)`

It occurs to me that regular expressions would be great for this and I found a program called "BULK RENAME UTILITY" (www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk) that supports using RegEx to rename files.

It has two fields, one called "match", where you can enter a regex pattern to break the filename into four pieces.

And another field called "replace", where you can enter something like `\3 - \4 (\1 - \2.mp4)` to put the filename back together as you like.

I've done some quick research but regexs are still largely Greek to me, so I was hoping someone here could help me putting a regex together that breaks down the filenames above into four parts (foo, date, place, title) and allows me to rearrange them as desired.

I'm hoping to learn from that so that maybe next time I can do it on my own!

Comment: Are titles always 3 words?

Comment: Is the place always exactly one word?

Comment: Are they all mp4s? If not, what are the possible extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If neither the place nor the company will ever contain a `.`, this should work:

```
^([^.]+)\.(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})\.([^.]+)(.*)\.([^.]+)$
```

The `^` anchors the regex to the start of the string (and the `$` at the end anchors it to the end).

The `([^.]+)` parts are groups of non-`.` characters (company and place, and extension).

`(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})` captures the date: digit repeated twice, followed by a period, etc.

The `(.*)` will capture the rest up to the last period (the title).

Comment: Amazing, thanks. Very helpful, worked and thanks to your explanation I was even able to modify it for the one wmv :-) Thanks again.

Comment: Updated for completeness to work for any extension (and capture it).